# How to read a button which contains text with asterisk in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library, testing-library

Can anyone please help me with the below statement

I am trying to get the element by text which contains asterisk

```
const readButton = test.getByText('Read the rules *');
```

Comment: What library do you use for testing?

Comment: Jest Library we are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```js
test.getByText(/^Read the rules \*$/)
```

To test regex you can use

https://regex101.com/

Docs about regex in testing-library are here

https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/

Second option:

```js
test.getByText(content => content === 'Read the rules *');
```